# Links inheriting div size

Tags: html, css

I'm coding a basic site skeleton (In case anyone needs to know, I'm decently skilled in HTML, but have trouble with `div`s and I'm currently learning CSS), and an issue occurred where the links to google on the site logo and links like "Contact" and "News" are inheriting the size of the whole fixed banner, named `thing`. (The banner looks a bit odd in the snippet, because it's fixed and meant for desktop.)

My code:

```css
::-moz-selection {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #00ffaa;
}
::selection {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #00ffaa;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00ffaa;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00D486;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ADFFE2;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00ffaa
}
.thing {
  background: #141414;
  position: fixed;
  left: -2%;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200%;
  height: 10%;
}
.Header {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: -15px;
  font-size: 300%;
}
.Header:hover {
  transition: .2s;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: -15px;
  font-size: 300%
}
#link1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 600px;
  top: -85px;
}
#link2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -37px;
  left: 150px;
}
#link3 {
  position: relative;
  top: -37px;
  left: 150px;
}
#link4 {
  position: relative;
  top: -37px;
  left: 150px;
}
#link5 {
  position: relative;
  top: -37px;
  left: 150px;
}
#bodycontainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #191919;
  height: 200%;
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image x-icon" href="http://i.imgur.com/umSIVuQ.png?1" />
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body background="http://i.imgur.com/6PQ1Mtl.png">
  <center>
    <div id="bodycontainer">
    </div>
  </center>

  <div class="thing"> <font face="Franklin Gothic Demi"><a href="https://google.com"><h1 class="Header">Site Logo</h1></a>
 
 <div id="link1"><a href="https://google.com"><p>News</p>
 <div id="link2"><a href="https://google.com"><p>Art</p>
 <div id="link3"><a href="https://google.com"><p>Comics</p>
 <div id="link4"><a href="https://google.com"><p>About</p>
 <div id="link5"><a href="https://google.com"><p>Contact</p>
 </a></a></a></a></a></div></div></div></div></div></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

(P.S, if anyone could give me help with the top banner, too, that'd be awesome :3 )

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/1/

HTML

```
<body background="http://i.imgur.com/6PQ1Mtl.png">
    <center>
        <div id="bodycontainer">
        </div>
    </center>

    <div class="thing"> <font face="Franklin Gothic Demi">
        <a class="Header" href="">Header</a>

        <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="https://google.com">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Art</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Comics</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
:-moz-selection {
color: #ffffff;
background: #00ffaa;
}
::selection {
color: #ffffff;
background: #00ffaa;
}
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00ffaa;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00D486;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ADFFE2;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00ffaa
}
.thing {
background: #141414;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
width: 100%;
}
a.Header {
color: #aaaaaa;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 30px;
margin-right: 15px;
}

.Header:hover {
color: #dbdbdb;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#bodycontainer {
position: relative;
background-color: #191919;
height: 200%;
width: 65%;
}

.navigation {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
}

ul {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navigation li a {
color: #00ffaa;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
color: #adffe2;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! I had no previous idea of navigation lists, so this info will help a lot :)